# How can I fix the problem of loading the model to get new predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, save

I trained a model and save it as `import os model.save('')` , I want to use my model to make prediction on new test set so I load it by `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('')` ..
it shows me this waring (**WARNING:tensorflow:SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5 detected when loading Keras model. Please ensure that you are saving the model with model.save() or tf.keras.models.save_model(), *NOT* tf.saved_model.save(). To confirm, there should be a file named "keras_metadata.pb" in the SavedModel directory.**)

The problem is now when I make prediction , it gives me inaccurate results.. it seems as the same prediction of the training/testing set not for the new one

Also , I notice that the tensoerflow type is 2.6 but when I saved the model it was 2.5 .. is this a problem ?
Please I need a help as soon as possible.

Comment: sooo... how did you save the model?

Answer (score 3):

This warning was added to encourage users to save keras models using `model.save` instead of `tf.saved_model.save`.

Saving keras models with `tf.saved_model.save` saves only base level data (like the graphdef / checkpoint) where as `model.save` saves the layer configs / trainable status / name / other python attributes along with graphdef / checkpoint.

This warning will not affect the model training or inference. I have used a simple `mnist` model to demonstrate that the warning is not going to affect the trained model. I have trained this `mnist` model with `TF2.5` and loaded with `tf-nightly`. After loading the model, I retrained the model and noticed there was no loss in the performance of the model.

For reference, Here is a [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/chunduriv/2fc639bc4f221fbe37d5df81315eef06/untitled30.ipynb) with `mnist` model that I mentioned above.